# Bridge-методы java

Tags: java, терминология

Прочёл в литературе, что в процессе **Type Erasure** (стирания типов) компилятор выполняет следующие действия:

1. добавляет приведение типов для обеспечения *type safety*, если это необходимо.
2. генерирует **Bridge-методы** для сохранения полиморфизма.

Объясните, что из себя представляют "Bridge-методы"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Возьмём для примера такой код

```
class Node<T> {
    public T data;

    public Node(T data) { this.data = data; }

    public void setData(T data) {
        System.out.println("Node.setData");
        this.data = data;
    }
}

class MyNode extends Node<Integer> {
    public MyNode(Integer data) { super(data); }

    public void setData(Integer data) {
        System.out.println("MyNode.setData");
        super.setData(data);
    }
}

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyNode mn = new MyNode(5);
        Node n = mn;
        n.setData("Hello");     
        Integer x = mn.data;
    }
}
```

После стирания типов выглядеть он будет так

```
public class Node {
    public Object data;

    public Node(Object data) { this.data = data; }

    public void setData(Object data) {
        System.out.println("Node.setData");
        this.data = data;
    }
}

public class MyNode extends Node {

    public MyNode(Integer data) { super(data); }

    public void setData(Integer data) {
        System.out.println("MyNode.setData");
        super.setData(data);
    }
}

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyNode mn = new MyNode(5);
        Node n = (MyNode) mn;
        n.setData("Hello");
        Integer x = (String) mn.data;
    }
}
```

Можно заметить, что после стирания типов сигнатуры метода `setData` в `MyNode` и `Node` больше не совпадают, а значит субкласс не переопределяет метод и полиморфизм оказывается сломан. Чтобы исправить эту ситуацию, компилятор генерирует для `MyNode` bridge-метод такого вида

```
public void setData(Object data) {
    setData((Integer) data);
}
```

Увидеть его можно, заглянуть в байткод с помощью команды `javap -c -v MyNode`

```
  public void setData(java.lang.Object);
    descriptor: (Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_BRIDGE, ACC_SYNTHETIC
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=2, args_size=2
         0: aload_0
         1: aload_1
         2: checkcast     #6                  // class java/lang/Integer
         5: invokevirtual #7                  // Method setData:(Ljava/lang/Integer;)V
         8: return
```

[Соответствующий раздел документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bridgeMethods.html).

Comment: @ИванСапронов потому что нельзя привести `String` к `Integer`. Пример так и задуман.

Comment: @ИванСапронов нет. `T` - это какой-то неопределённый тип. Он заменяется на тип `Object` в процессе компиляции. Сам метод никуда не девается. И bridge-метод добавляет в `MyNode`, а не в `Node`.

Comment: спасибо! Разобрался с примером и теперь всё встало на свои места.